# How to end a list in python?

Tags: python, list, recursion

I have to write a code that produces a list using recursion, but the final item in the list needs to be empty. This is my code and what I need it to produce vs what it actually is producing.

```
def coin_change(avail_change, total_cents):
    if avail_change == []:
        return []
    if total_cents // avail_change[0] >= 1:
        first = total_cents // avail_change[0]
        first_list = [avail_change[0], first]
        return [first_list, coin_change(avail_change[1:], (total_cents - (avail_change[0] * first)))]
    else:
        return coin_change(avail_change[1:], total_cents)
```

Result:

```
coin_change([50,5,1],108) => [[50,2],[5,1],[1,3]]
expected [[50, 2], [5, 1], [1, 3]], saw [[50, 2], [[5, 1], [[1, 3], []]]]
```

I need to make the list end after `[1,3]` but I don't know what to do.

Comment: Why are you returning an empty list if you're left with an empty list?

Comment: Note that the pythonic way to check for an empty list is `if not some_list:` as opposed to `if some_list == []:`.

Comment: Change `[first_list, coin_change(avail_change[1:], (total_cents - (avail_change[0] * first)))]` to `[first_list] + coin_change(avail_change[1:], (total_cents - (avail_change[0] * first)))`. `[list1, list2]` is not equal to `[list1] + list2`.

Comment: Is there actually particular reason you're addressing this with recursion?

Answer (score 1):

When you use recursion, think first what is your base case, and how it is combined with the previous calls. In this problem, if you do `return [first_list, ...` then you are nesting the results. Instead of this, you have to insert the new results in the same list.

```
def coin_change(avail_change, total_cents):
    if not avail_change:
        return []
    else:
        first = total_cents // avail_change[0]
        result = coin_change(avail_change[1:], (total_cents % avail_change[0]))
        if first > 0:
            result.insert(0, [avail_change[0], first])
        return result

print coin_change([50,5,1],108) # [[50, 2], [5, 1], [1, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a list for each recursive call, and therefore the result is one of increasingly nested lists.

You should also return two-tuples rather than lists. Lists are intended to be mutable and non-fixed length, but your (denomination, count) pairs are neither.

Also, just for fun, what would be the output of `coin_change([3,2],16)`, and what would you expect it to be?

Answer (score 0):

```
first_list = []


def coin_change(avail_change, total_cents):
    if not avail_change:
        return []

    if total_cents // avail_change[0] >= 1:
        first = total_cents // avail_change[0]
        first_list.append([avail_change[0], first])
        coin_change(avail_change[1:], (total_cents - (avail_change[0] * first)))

    else:
        coin_change(avail_change[1:], total_cents)

    return first_list

x = coin_change([50, 5, 1], 108)
print x
```

Result:
[[50, 2], [5, 1], [1, 3]] as you wanted

x = coin_change([ ], 108)
print x

outputs [ ]

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
coins = []
def coin_change(avail_change, total_cents):
    if avail_change == []:
        raise Exception()
    if total_cents // avail_change[0] >= 1:
        first = total_cents // avail_change[0]
        first_list = [avail_change[0], first]
        coins.append(first_list)
        try:
            return coin_change(avail_change[1:], (total_cents - (avail_change[0] * first)))
        except:
            return coins
    else:
        try:
            return coin_change(avail_change[1:], total_cents)
        except:
            return coins
```

Result:

```
>>> coin_change ([50,5,1], 108)
[[50, 2], [5, 1], [1, 3]]
```